# Exchange Server : ItemId.UniqueId is changing

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've got a software i'm working on that pulls in emails from an exchange account.  I use the ItemId.UniqueId to save to db.  This allows me to check all incoming messages to see if they've been processed before.

The problem is that i'm seeing some messages come in twice.  I can't work out why, though i can see that the UniqueId is different, so it's been updated.

I know if you move an email to a folder it give is a new UniqueId - which will then look like a new message...

Is there a way that I can get around this?  Is there an ID that doesn't change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PidTagSearchKey https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815908.aspx doesn't change be isn't guaranteed to be unique (see table in doc) eg if somebody copies a Message between folders then the PidTagSearchKey will be the same, but for what you want to use it for it should do the trick.